# Docker compose, build unknown

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I am really new to Docker. When I execute in the terminal `docker-compose --version` I get:

```
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build unknown
```

What does it mean 'build unknown' and when should it change from unknown to another value?

I'll appreciate any guidence.

Answer (score 0):

Mine says

```
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c
```

The build identifier corresponds to a git commit id. This commit to be specific: https://github.com/docker/compose/commit/5becea4ca9f68875334c92f191a13482bcd6e5cf

So it gives you a way to see exactly what the source code looked like when the version was built.

I don't know why yours says 'unknown'. Perhaps the build pipeline that made it didn't stamp it with the commit id for some reason.